# Why can't I use/import a ttk theme in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was trying to use a `ttk` theme named **"Sun Vally"** ([Link](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme)) But when I tried to use it, it gave an error of `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sv_ttk'"` even though I already have pip installed it.. I am still new to all this.. thanks in advance!

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure that the same `Python` environment (which `sv_ttk` is installed) is used to execute your script?

Comment: Yes. I even did the `pip list` thing and saw that I had it

Comment: If you use same Python environment, I wonder why you got such error.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, try running the command `pip list` in your terminal. Does the module `sv_ttk 1.0` appear in the list? If not, you may need to try running `pip install sv-ttk` again. This also assumes you aren't using a Python virtual environment, but I imagine you aren't.

You may also want to check if the module is properly installing into your `site packages` directory (the location of which is platform dependent). Are you on Mac OS or Windows?

Please update this question with a minimal example of what you've already tried so we can help you further.

Comment: I checked and I had it on the list already. And I'm on Windows.

Comment: What development environment are you using? VS Code? IDLE? Also, check in `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<the version you're using>\Lib\site-packages` - that's where pip should install things by default. Is there a folder for `sv-ttk` (or something similar)? And lastly, do you have multiple versions of Python on your machine?

Comment: Found it at like `C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\sv_ttk` like you said. and I have only the newest version of python

Answer (score 0):

IF FIGURED IT OUT! I was using `cmd` to install pip but never realized I needed to use a different terminal... Turns out `PyCharm` has its own terminal and wont work if you used a different one...